# Получить количество посещений за последнюю неделю за каждый день

Tags: mysql, sql

таблица имеет вид
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
пишу запрос

```
 SELECT  COUNTER_DATE,PEOPLE, COUNT(PEOPLE) FROM counter
 where WEEK(`date`, 1) = WEEK(NOW(), 1) GROUP BY COUNTER_DATE;
```

Запрос не работает,как поправить?

Comment: `COUNT` -> `SUM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал запрос и всё заработало

```
SELECT  COUNTER_DATE,PEOPLE, sum(PEOPLE) FROM ip_counter
where  WEEK(`COUNTER_DATE`, 1) = WEEK(NOW(), 1) GROUP BY DATE(COUNTER_DATE);
```